# jquery draggable and resizable is not working on cloned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a `div` with draggable and resizable functionality of `jQuery UI`. I clone the `div` and append it to the same parent:

```
<div class="drag resize"> ... </div>

$(".drag").live("mouseenter", function() { $(this).draggable(); });
$(".resize").live("mouseenter", function() { $(this).resizable(); });

$("div").clone(true).appendTo($("div").parent());
```

The clone is created successfully, but when I am trying to drag it, the orignal one drags. Resizing is also not working. Can anybody explain me what is happening here?

Comment: This code is pretty confusing, why are you attaching the draggable and resizable on `mouseenter`?

Comment: because "ready" and "load" are not working with .live() , so i want some event to trigger

Comment: Live is deprecated. Try [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to look at this SO post [jQuery UI resizable cloned element(.clone(true)) doesn't resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829270/jquery-ui-resizable-cloned-element-clonetrue-doesnt-resize)
- the removal of the resize handlers before applying a resizable() on the cloned element worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `.on` event handler instead and attach it to the parent of this div.

```
$(".drag").parent().on("mouseenter", ".drag", function() { $(this).draggable(); });
```