# When I clone a draggable div, why isn't the clone draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a cloned div draggable :

```
 $("div").clone(true).removeAttr("id").appendTo($("body")).draggable();
```

I've also tried this:

```
 $("div").clone(true,true).removeAttr("id").appendTo($("body")).draggable();
```

It creates a clone but that clone is not draggable. Can anybody tell me why this is not working?

Comment: Are you still using `live()`?

Comment: yes "live" is there and i tried "on" also that also not worked, but now i am making the "cloned div", draggable, explicitly, now also it is not dragging

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10672555/913097, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10672180/913097

Comment: @inhan I wanted to do the same, but I guess it's not really a duplicate, since he's attempted to solve the issue with those answers and hasn't been successful.

Comment: No it is not , this case is different

Comment: yes @jivings help me out

Comment: can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I am searching about this from the morning but i did`nt find a single post or artical with exact answer or solution that why Jquery UI draggable and resizable plugins are not working with "clones" Or any workaround for this

Comment: @user1400722 I have solved it for you, now please stop asking :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not we first destroy the orignal elements draggale and resizable plugins like :

```
$("#orignaldivid").draggable("destroy");
$("#orignaldivid").resizable("destroy");
```

Then make a clone like :

```
  var clone = $("orignaldivid").clone(true).attr("id", GetNewId()); //GetNewId may be any function to generate unique id
```

Then append it to the `#orignaldiv parent` like :

```
  $(clone).appendTo($("#orignaldivid").parent());
```

And finally `re-assign to orignal` and `assign to clone` all plugins

```
$("#orignaldivid").draggable();
$("#orignaldivid").resizable();
$(clone).draggable();
$(clone).resizable();
```

May be helpful !

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. You don't want to `clone(true)`. Just `clone()`. The former will clone the draggable event as well, which is why it has that weird behaviour.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/byZXS/1/

```
$('div').draggable(); 
$('div').clone().appendTo('body').draggable();​
```

How to preserve the data:

```
var data = $('div').data();
var newDiv = $("div").clone().appendTo('body').draggable();
newDiv.data(data);
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/byZXS/2/

Comment: it worked fine thanks a lot , but now how will i copy the other related data with div

Comment: Its only a single Key which i entered through .data(), whose initial value is 0 ,so i entered it manually in the cloned div but if there is some workaround for this, then i am curious to know because in this case it is a single key but what if there are 100s of key

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. `clone()` should copy everything in the `div`.

Comment: It not copies the data which we insert through .data(), means suppose i inserted "a" with starting value 0 like $("div").data("a",0); then this "a" is not copied with .clone()

Comment: You can just copy the old data to the new element. I'll update my answer.